# Securing my RESTful API with API Key + Secret On Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, authentication, express

I have built a REStful API on Express and I would like to secure it with an authentication which requires a Public key, Hashed Private Key, and a Nonce as Headers similar to the way [Coinbase](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#authentication) or [Potcoin](https://potwallet.com/developers/docs) operate. Problem is I cannot find the right library with an example of how to implement it. The closest is probably [HMMAC](https://github.com/cmawhorter/hmmac), however its example does't work and it is even started in the file. My question is, how should I implement such a security for the REST API. Note that it has sensitive information for every user such as balance e.t.c and it is meant for developers to consume our service. I just want to secure every GET, POST, PATCH endpoint on the API.

Comment: I've read tons of articals and blogposts about RESTful API's and how to secure it. I think you should take a look at [JWT](https://jwt.io/) (JSON Web Tokens). With JWTs you can securely transmit information between parties as a **JSON** object. It can be verified and trusted because it is signed with a secret (with the **HMAC** algorithm) or public/private key pair using **RSA**. Another easy way is to simply use [Oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/).

Answer (score 0):

---

Used JWT as suggested, and it works fairly well.